# Trouble Understanding NEXTVAL and CURRVAL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I did search for a similar question, but if I overlooked an existing answer I am glad to be redirected there.

I am working to untangle an Oracle Stored Proceedure in a legacy system written by a long departed developer.

The focus of the proceedure is to upload user data into the existing table structure in a bulk collection and save keystroke time adding 1-x-1 records.

The procedure appears to work without error and the user group would like to expand it to allow additional data to load to separate but related tables.

The author is using the NEXTVAL and CURRVAL commands to add primary key information as new records are added using the CSV data.

But I am confused because my understanding of NEXTVAL/CURRVAL was that they required context and declaration to be used correctly.

For example the Proceedure has the following:

```
SELECT seq_site.nextval INTO v_curr
FROM DUAL;
```

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET site_id = seq_site.currval
```

However [SEQ_SITE] is not declared anywhere in the preceding lines of the Procedure.

Am I inferring correctly that the clause [SELECT seq_site.nextval INTO v_curr] is the declaration for [SEQ_Record_count]?

(...v_curr is declared an integer early in the procedure declarations btw...)

Comment: SEQ_SITE is a sequence object that exists separately from the stored procedure so there is no need to declare its existence before using the nextval. SELECT seq_site.nextval INTO v_curr is a SELECT INTO statement and is unrelated to the defintion/declaration of SEQ_SITE sequence object.

Comment: fyi, `nextval` and `currval` are methods of the sequence object, not commands.

Comment: Also, you haven't needed to `select someseq.nextval into somevar from dual` for at least a decade. If you want it in a variable, just assign it.

Comment: Thank you all for some great notes!  But especially William and ivanzg!!  (...and by extension Chris Ostrowski)

Here are a couple of links for future readers that your notes helped me realize I needed to learn about.

[Oracle Sequences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJXpjrrZHFE)   AND   [Oracle Dual Table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Q7LWKl6vsU)